# Only show the highest amount on an INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

We have an interactive Map of America which shows the state which equals your requirement.

We have an Problem with our Database, we have two tables `staaten` and `economydata`.

Our inner join

```
SELECT staaten.staat_id, staat_name, economydata.INDUSTRY_ID, economydata.INDUSTRIE_UMSATZ_ANTEIL 
FROM staaten, economydata 
WHERE staaten.staat_id = economydata.staat_i;`
```

gives us this output:

```
staat_id    staat_name    INDUSTRY_ID     INDUSTRIE_UMSATZ_ANTEIL   
1           Alabama       3               1
1           Alabama       6               1
1           Alabama       10              3
1           Alabama       11              4
1           Alabama       12              18
1           Alabama       13              11
1           Alabama       25              7
1           Alabama       34              6
1           Alabama       35              7 
1           Alabama       36              3
1           Alabama       45              2
1           Alabama       51              5
1           Alabama       56              11
1           Alabama       60              6
1           Alabama       64              1
1           Alabama       65              3
1           Alabama       69              1
1           Alabama       70              7
1           Alabama       75              0
1           Alabama       78              3
1           Alabama       81              3
1           Alabama       82              17
2           Alaska        3               2
2           Alaska        6               16
2           Alaska        10              2
2           Alaska        11              4
2           Alaska        12              3
2           Alaska        13              0
2           Alaska        25              3
2           Alaska        34              2
2           Alaska        35              4
2           Alaska        36              12
2           Alaska        45              3
2           Alaska        51              3
2           Alaska        56              9
2           Alaska        60              4
2           Alaska        64              1
2           Alaska        65              2
2           Alaska        69              0
2           Alaska        70              7
2           Alaska        75              1
2           Alaska        78              3
2           Alaska        81              2
2           Alaska        82              21
```

But we only need one row per Staate which only contains the Highest `economydata.INDUSTRIE_UMSATZ_ANTEIL` with the `INDUSTRY_ID`.

The closest we got was with `SELECT ... MAX(economydata.INDUSTRIE_UMSATZ_ANTEIL) FROM ... GROUP BY staaten.staat_name` but we lost the connection between `economydata.INDUSTRIE_UMSATZ_ANTEIL` and `INDUSTRY_ID`, it showed us the Highest `INDUSTRIE_UMSATZ_ANTEIL` but not the right `INDUSTRY_ID`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+groupwise+maximum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a tuple and a in clause on the result for max(INDUSTRIE_UMSATZ_ANTEIL) group by staat_id

```
  SELECT 
      staaten.staat_id
    , staat_name
    , economydata.INDUSTRY_ID
    , economydata.INDUSTRIE_UMSATZ_ANTEIL 
  FROM staaten
  INNER JOIN  economydata on staaten.staat_id = economydata.staat_i
  where (staaten.staat_id, economydata.INDUSTRIE_UMSATZ_ANTEIL ) in (
        SELECT 
        staaten.staat_id
      , max(economydata.INDUSTRIE_UMSATZ_ANTEIL) 
    FROM staaten
    INNER JOIN  economydata on staaten.staat_id = economydata.staat_i
    group by  staaten.staat_id

  )
```

and i suggest the use of explicit join  instead that where clause  ... the code is more clear

Comment: Awesome, worked perfectly. Would you mind to explain why we use this line `where (staaten.staat_id, economydata.INDUSTRIE_UMSATZ_ANTEIL )` ?

Comment: Is a the simple way for compare two columns,  (these are called  tuple) instead that use two join condition ..  .. mysql  allowed  the use of the tuple and are very useful for me